# Adding a custom indicator to ChartSeries Quantmod

Tags: r, quantmod, quantstrat

I have created the chandelier indicator. The function is:

```
chandlier_exit_long = function(x,k = 3,  
 n = 22){
 high = rollapplyr(Hi(x), width = n, FUN 
 = max)
 atr = ATR(x, n)[, "atr"]
  z = high - atr
 names(z) = "Chandelier_Exit_Long"
 return(z)
}
```

I have used quantmods function newTA to create:

```
  addChandExitLong = newTA(FUN = 
  chandlier_exit_long, preFUN = OHLC, col 
  = "red")
```

I am getting an error
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a *warning*, not an error. Though it does indicate something is not quite right.  The problem is that `rollapplyr` does not pad/fill with `NA` by default. So you need to change your function to:

```
chandlier_exit_long = function(x, k = 3, n = 22){
  high = rollapplyr(Hi(x), n, FUN = max, fill = NA)  # add `fill = NA`
  atr = ATR(x, n)[, "atr"]
  z = high - atr
  names(z) = "Chandelier_Exit_Long"
  return(z)
}
```

Or you could replace the `rollapplyr()` call with `runMax(Hi(x), n)`.